# Xamarin forms: IOS app rejected by app store review team with issue Missing Info.plist key

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, info.plist

I submitted my first iOS app to the app store and they rejected the app because of the following issue:

> **Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's
>   Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a
>   string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

By researching, I found the solution and I added NSCalendarsUsageDescription to the Info.plist like below:

[image]

I re-submited the app after fixing it but app was rejected again by the app store with the same issue.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Privacy key "Privacy - Calendars Usage Description".

Comment: Hi Ramya
Now I fix all those issues and I need to resubmit the app. What are the steps to submit the app again for the review?

I already created the IPA file and upload it using application loader, the new Build is not come live in itunesconnect, when it comes in the Build section can I press the submit for review button? Is there any additional steps for this?

Comment: @SreejithSree Yes, you need to fill all the details and click on "Submit for Review". You will have to wait until your app goes through the approval process and becomes live.

Comment: I have a strange problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532559/xamarin-forms-rest-apis-are-not-working-on-real-devices

Comment: Do you have any idea about this issue?